# Can the Mermaids create towns with +1 shipping bonus?

Tags: terra-mystica

Is it possible for the mermaids to create a new town with their special ability when they have the bonus +1 shipping card?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shipping, whether regular shipping or the temporary shipping bonus, would not have an impact on the mermaid towns. Even with shipping, towns cannot be founded across river; it only counts direct adjacency. So yes, even if they have a shipping bonus, the mermaids could found a town by placing the town marker on the river space that connects 2 half-towns.